# PHP Array results - assign to their own variable

Tags: php, variables

Hi here are my query results

```
transsum
-19121111
-17432222
-19873333
-22404444
-21955555
-19716666
```

I need to place each one of the results into it's own variable

I have this but I don't think it's right

```
$arr_results = odbc_exec($TD_DB_RESOURCE, $query);
foreach ($row = odbc_fetch_array($arr_results) )  
{
    $price0 = $row[0];
    $price1 = $row[1];
    $price2 = $row[2];
    $price3 = $row[3];
    $price4 = $row[4];
    $price5 = $row[5];
}
```

Updated code

```
$TD_DB_RESOURCE = open_teradata_resource();
$arr_results = odbc_exec($TD_DB_RESOURCE, $query);
$rows = array();
$i=0;
while ($myRow = odbc_fetch_array($arr_results) )  
{
$rows[$i] = $myRow;
$i++;
}
```

outputs

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [TOTAL] => -19126241 ) [1] => Array ( [TOTAL] => -17439360 ) [2] => Array ( [TOTAL] => -19871999 ) [3] => Array ( [TOTAL] => -22409254 ) [4] => Array ( [TOTAL] => -21950605 ) [5] => Array ( [TOTAL] => -19710526 ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is an array with totals, you can use this:

```
$prices = [];
while ($myRow = odbc_fetch_array($arr_results)) {
    $prices[] = $myRow['TOTAL'];
}
```

Afterwards, the contents of `$prices` should be:

```
[-19126241, -17439360, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create variables with curly braces:

```
$arr_results = odbc_exec($TD_DB_RESOURCE, $query);
$count = 0;
foreach ($row = odbc_fetch_array($arr_results)) {
    $price{$count} = $row;
    $count++;
 }
```

Comment: I just tried this and it causes my script to break and throw a 500 error

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<?php
    $arr_result ...
    $index=0;
    foreach($row = odbc_fetch_array($arr_results)){
        ${'price'.$index++} = $row;
    }
```

Comment: I just tried this and it causes my script to break and throw a 500 error

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr_results = odbc_exec($TD_DB_RESOURCE, $query);
$i=0;
$prices = array(); //Make a dynamic array of elements
foreach ($row = odbc_fetch_array($arr_results) )  
{
  $prices[$i] = $row[$i];
  $i++;
}
```

Then use the array elements anywhere in you calculations like

```
$c = $price[0]+$price[1];
```

Comment: I just tried this and it causes my script to break and throw a 500 error

Comment: beginning of my query  - select SUM(transaction_usd_equiv_amt) as TOTAL

Comment: great you found the anwer